# What does という do in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from a dialogue with my language partner.

For some context:
もちろん、学習法は人によって違います。私は多角的に学んでいくのが好きです。本を読む、ラジオや映画を観るのは1人でもできます。この２つは reading と listening の練習になります。文章を書く（writing）も1人でできますが、相手がいる方が楽しいですよね。会話（speaking) の練習も1人でできますが、会話の目的はコミュニケーションなので、相手がいた方がいいです。
コミュニケーションしたいという強い気持ちがあれば、リーディングもリスニングもライティングも、もっとずっと楽しくなります。がんばろうという強い動機（motivation) になるからです。
こうやってメッセージのやりとりをするのも、コミュニケーションの1つですよね。

The two sentences in question:
コミュニケーションしたいという強い気持ちがあれば、リーディングもリスニングもライティングも、もっとずっと楽しくなります。がんばろうという強い動機（motivation) になるからです。

My attempt at translation:
"When there is a strong

A)...communicationmotivation..
B)...motivation called communication...

Reading and Writing become much more enjoyable.
This is because it becomes a
...A) 'let's do this'-motivation."
...B) motivation called 'let's do this'."

The problem is that I very well know that という is in many cases NOT to be translated literally (="he/she/it says or "is called"). I also know that it has many more functions than just marking a designation/description for the following noun. I must also admit though that I'm having a very hard time describing these other functions and therefore my skills handling these cases where the other functions apply are not the best. 
So, while I understand what she wants to tell me, I don't really know what function という is taking the respective sentences. It also confuses me A LOT how がんばろうという強い動機 works, since here a set expression is attached to the following nominal phrase. I haven't encountered something like that by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key word here is ***apposition/appositive***.

> 「Word/Phrase/Mini-Sentence + という + Noun/Noun Phrase」

What is said on either side of 「という」 is in apposition to the other.  To put it most simply, the two sides are in an "A = B" relationship.

> 「がんばろう**という**強{つよ}い動機{どうき}」

「がんばろう」 is in apposition to 「強い動機」.

> "a strong motivation to do my best"

Other examples:

「いつか日本に行きたい**という**夢{ゆめ}」 = "a/the/one's dream of going to Japan some day"

「毎日{まいにち}３時間勉強{じかんべんきょう}しなさい**という**アドバイス」= "the/one's advice to study 3 hours daily"

What I have often heard from Japanese-learners is that the fact that the verbs preceding the 「という」 can come in different forms (such as imperative, volitional, etc.) throws them off.  I think I understand their feeling, but as far as translation is concerned, I would suggest that they use "(noun) to (verb)" or "(noun) of (verb)ing" as I did in all of the examples above.  It would be awkward to use something like "let's" in the translation.