# What is the function of the という、 here?

Tags: grammar

彼女は頰を紅潮させ歯を食いしばる**という**、駄々っ子のような表情を作りながら、肩をいからせるような姿勢でその場に立ち上がった。

Hi. What is the function of the bold part?
Can we omit it?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55487/9831

Comment: @Chocolate So this という modifies 表情 and signals an appositive clause, right?

Comment: @chinoalpha Yes, exactly.